# how to remove these characters from a string c () \ ][ ""

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I have a string like this

```
st <- "c(c(c(\"E\" >= \"E\", \"B\" <= \"E\" | \"D\" <= \"B\"), \"A\" >= \"C\" | \"A\" >= \"A\"), c(\"E\" >= \"C\", \"D\" <= \"C\" | \"C\" <= \"C\")) []"
```

I want to remove these characters from it    `c () \ ][ ""`

i would like to get this

```
"E >= E, B <= E | D <= B, A >= C | A >= A, E >= C, D <= C | C <= C"
```

Comment: Check out the `gsub` function. That said, your input looks like this might not be sufficient to make it actually usable, and you might need to build an actual expression parser — or use R’s builtin parser.

Comment: I tried , but I couldn't get this to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach that could solve your problem:

```
gsub('[c()"]| \\[\\]', "", st)

# [1] "E >= E, B <= E | D <= B, A >= C | A >= A, E >= C, D <= C | C <= C"
```